# Как настроить Zabbix-agent на использование PowerShell x64

Tags: windows, powershell, zabbix

При работе с Zabbix-agent на Windows 2012R2 столкнулся с такой проблемой: при настройке пользовательского параметра я указываю команду **Get-Website** и дальше пытаюсь выполнить **zabbix_agent -t my_param**. В ответ вместо необходимого параметра я получаю:

```
[t|Get-Website : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_C...
```

Немного поискав в интернете понял, что это связано с тем, что команда не работает в Shell x86. Попробовал ту же команду в Shell x86 и получил, собственно, ту же ошибку (x64 эта команда работает).
В документации как явно запускать Shell x64 я не нашёл. В списке программ, что x86, что x64 ведут к одному и тому же файлу запуска.
Прошу, подскажите что делать.

Comment: Нужно правильно установить и зарегистрировать необходимый COM компонент.

Comment: Что-то я не могу найти ничего по этому поводу. Не могли бы дать ссылку или маленькое объяснение, чтобы мне было от чего отталкиваться. Спасибо

Comment: Проще говоря, перустановите agent. Необходимая документация по развертыванию, в том числе и на русском языке, находится на сайте производителя.